# Winjs promise return a value

Tags: typescript, winjs

I need to return a value from a Winjs promise, something like this:

```
getString() {
        var str: string;
        new WinJS.Promise((completed, error) => { Test.getAString(completed, error); })
                         .done((s: string) => str = s);
        return str;
    }
```

The problem is str always returns undefined, but s has a value (ie "test") which I get in debug mode.

Thanks in advance to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the `str` variable is undefined is because it is returned before the promise is fulfilled. I assume `Test.getAString` is asynchronous. It takes a little time before it completes. So `return str;` is executed before it is done.

A way to overcome this is to return the promise and, instead of handling the `done`-function here, handle the fulfillment when getting the string.

So you get something like:

```
getString().then((s:string)=> do something with the string.. );

function getString(){
    return new WinJS.Promise((completed, error) => { 
        Test.getAString(completed, error); 
    });
}
```

Comment: I will have to wait for async/await implementation. Thank you.